# Spring Security login don't work

Tags: hibernate, spring-security

I have an application on which you can login with your username and your password... and each user has an role. I use Hibernate ORM.

My login mechanism doesn't work, I use Spring Security for this. These are my classes:

Manager class:

```
package com.abt.fiifootballmanager.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Manager.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM Manager m")
public class Manager implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long managerId;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String username;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable
    private List<Role> roles;
    //+getters and setters 
    }
```

Role class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Role\"")
@NamedQuery(name="Role.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Role r")
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long roleId;

    private String role;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<Manager> managers;
    //+getters and setters
}
```

This is my authentication-manager from security.xml:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>

        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="select Manager.username, Role.role from Manager
                                           join Manager_Role on Manager.managerId = Manager_Role.MANAGERS_MANAGERID
                                           join Role on Manager_Role.roles_roleId = Role.roleId
                                           where Manager.username = ?"
            users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from Manager where name = ?" />

    </authentication-provider>

 <!-- because I use a many-to-many relationship, Hibernate create a new 
    table, named Manager_Role, with next columns: MANAGERS_MANAGERID and roles_roleId -->
</authentication-manager>
```

This is my login form:

```
    <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />" method="POST">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" name="j_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus> 
    <input type="password" name="j_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required> 
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that nothing is happening when I try to login with an username and a password from my db ... and no exception is thrown. How can I figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

this is not spring security, you have to read about Spring Security and understand its architecture, there some Implementations and configurations,
try to follow these tutorials

http://keylesson.com/index.php/java-ee/spring-security/

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/